# how to i mapped 2 csv file with different header name and total column in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2csv

csv1
header=id,name,country

csv2
header=memberid,fullname,dob,whatever,country

how do i moved all my data from csv1 to csv2? id==memberid and name==fulname

Comment: Open both the files and store as list containing each line `file1 = open("csv1.csv").read().split("\n")` then you can replace data in that line using list indexing , if your header is lets say the 5th line in the file, then you would do `file1[5] = file2[5]` to replace that line with the line from file2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas for this.
You can install pandas package with `pip install pandas`.

1. Read csv files to a dataframe,

```
import pandas as pd

csv1 = pd.read_csv('path/for/csv1') 
csv2 = pd.read_csv('path/for/csv2')
```

2. Now merge both based on column mappings,

```
new_csv = pd.merge(csv1,csv2,left_on=['id','name'], right_on=['memberid','fullname'])
```

optionally drop the duplicate columns `new_csv.drop(['memberid','fullname'],axis=1)`

3. Now export to new csv as

```
new_csv.to_csv('path/to/new.csv')
```